# How to start deps application automatcially in Chicago Boss?

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I can't figure out how to automatically start an "deps" applciation in Chicago Boss.

Use `applcation:which_applications()` I can see a bunch started like "lager, ranch, cowboy ..etc etc". How do I start another one I added?

If I go to console and run `application:start(oauth2)` and  it's ok. I can start it.

But I tried to change `src/xxx.app.src` and add it to `{applications,[]}`, but no go. Isn't this the place to load/start any application that mine depends on?

But I can't find how boss loads and start all the other applications either.

By the way, this oauth2 appliation doesn't contain an application-behavior file (oauth2_app.erl) so I don't know if this is related. Since I can manually start it ok.

So, confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Plus: I remember that I did start application by adding the `application:start(xxx)` into the `/priv/init/xxx_01_news.erl` `init` function but that's very hackish I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rebar.config` to add your dependency applications then edit [`boss.config`](https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/ChicagoBoss/wiki/Configuration) file this way:

- First: Add the dependency applications name in `applications`.
- Second: Add their specific configurations as follows.

**boss.config** file:

```
[
   {boss, [
      {path, "./deps/boss"},
      {applications, [your_app_name, your_app_dep_1, your_app_dep_2]},
      {assume_locale, "en"},

%% ... other configuration

%% APPLICATION CONFIGURATIONS
   {your_app_name, []},
   {your_app_dep_1, []},
   {your_app_dep_2, []}                                                                                                                                                                  
].
```

---

**Edit:** This way CB expects another boss application so looks for the router file and warns if cannot find it. However starting the dependencies inside its `init` function is not a dirty way and I suggest to consider it.

Comment: It works. But the console has error "missing or invalid boss.routes file in "deps/oauth2/priv/boss.routes" {error, enoent}. It seems expecting a boss application.

Comment: @Jusfeel Yes it expects another boss application so looks for the router file. However starting the dependencies inside the `init` function is not a dirty way and I suggest to consider it. I edited the answer with this.